# Python 2 to 3 issue warnings

Tags: python

I recently came across some pretty "shy" bugs from running python2 code with python3. The reason was automatic conversion of integer division to float. So even though I didn't do this:

```
from __future__ import division
```

my code could run, the wrong way though.

I'm aware of [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) but the issues are the following:

- I don't see it mentioning anything about division, does it take care of it?
- I can't have a black box altering my code, is it a common practice to run it and use a diff tool to review the changes?
- I need a tool that would just issue warnings for my python2 code. Is there one?
- Is there an alternative?

Thanks in advance for your time, feedback on any of the questions will be very helpful.

Comment: See [`DeprecationWarning`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=deprecationwarning#miscellaneous-options) in the documentation. The -Wd option can be used to re-enable them. Code can also turn them on with `warnings.simplefilter('default')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 by default implements behavior of `division` module from `__future__`.

Python 2:

```
>>> 1.0 / 2.0
0.5
>>> 1/2
0
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1.0 / 2.0
0.5
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

Python 3:

```
>>> 1.0 / 2.0
0.5
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

To achieve behavior characteristic for version 2 use `//` operator:

```
>>> 1//2
0
>>> 1.0 // 2.0
0.0
```